# Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

A pupil conducting a coin tossing experiment  was surprised when she dropped 20 coins on to the floor and obtained only 5 heads.

Calculate using an appropriate binomial distribution the probability that 20 fair coins dropped onto the floor at random will show exactly 5 heads.

My attempt,

$$\begin{align}\Pr(X{=}5) &={^{20}{\sf C}_5}(0.25)^5(0.75)^{15}
\\[1ex]
& =0.2023\end{align}$$

But the answer given is $0.0148$. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you used the number of heads from the sample drops to calculate the probability, but you are dropping a **fair** coin. Thus the probability of heads is $0.5$, as is tails. Hence your probability is given by 
$$
{20 \choose 5} (0.5)^{5}(0.5)^{15}
$$

Comment: The event of $5$ heads $\big/20$ coins likely confused Mathxx. ...  It happens.